# Make a database (Oracle 7.3) consisting of several .DBF files into one .MDF file (Oracle dump file)

Tags: windows-7, database, dump

Can you make a database (Oracle 7.3) consisting of several .DBF files into one .MDF file (Oracle dump file) in Windows 7 or so.

Is there a tool that can do that "export" ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can not do that. .DBF is Oracle format while .MDF is MS SQL format.
The only way is to run a tool which connects onto both databases and copies data online.
Or you have to dump OracleDB into plain text file(s).